# Using getattr function on self in python

Tags: python, getattr

I am trying to write call multiple functions through a loop using the `getattr(...)`. Snippet below:

```
class cl1(module):
     I =1
     Name= 'name'+str(I)
     Func= 'func'+str(I)
     Namecall = gettattr(self,name)
     Namecall = getattr(self,name)()
```

This is when get the following code: `self.name1 = self.func1()`

The desire is to loop multiple of these but the code is not working. Can you please advise?

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. `Class` needs to be `class` (and you should read PEP 8 and fix the rest of your capitalization.) I'm assuming "not working" means the first line is a syntax error, because you haven't told us what it actually means.

Comment: `self` only exists inside a bound method; you don't have any methods here, nor is it clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MartijnPieters or more correctly, `self` only exists when you use the name `self` for the first argument of a bounded method, as the first argument will be assigned a reference to the current object.

Comment: @l4mpi: yes, but I didn't want to make it more confusing to the OP still. The [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) and how it relates to methods is not something I'd throw at beginners.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, do use CapitalLetters for Classes and lowercase_letters for variables as it is easier to read for other Python programmers :)

Now, you don't need to use getattr() inside the class itself
Just do :

```
self.attribute
```

However, an example will be:

```
class Foo(object):            # Class Foo inherits from 'object'
    def __init__(self, a, b): # This is the initialize function. Add all arguments here
        self.a = a  # Setting attributes
        self.b = b

    def func(self):
        print('Hello World!' + str(self.a) + str(self.b))

>>> new_object = Foo(a=1, b=2) # Creating a new 'Foo' object called 'new_object'
>>> getattr(new_object, 'a') # Getting the 'a' attribute from 'new_object'
1
```

However, an easier way would just be referencing the attribute directly

```
>>> new_object.a
1
>>> new_object.func()
Hello World!12
```

Or, by using getattr():

```
>>> getattr(new_object, 'func')()
Hello World!12
```

Although I explained the getattr() function,
I don't seem to understand what you want to achieve, do post a sample output.